# Mudar projeto c# .Net 4.6 para .Net4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

Teria alguma forma de mudar a verão do .Net utilizada no meu projeto para uma versão anterior ?

No meu projeto está com .NET 4.6 e gostaria de voltar para a versão .NET 4.5 sem ter que refaze tudo ?

Comment: E por que faria isto?

Comment: @Maniero Estou tentando subir meu projeto para o servidor onde está rodando a versão 4.5 do .NET e meu projeto esta com a versão 4.6

Comment: O ideal é atualizar o servidor, não acha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Vá em  gerenciador de solução 
2 - Clique com o  botão  direito em cima  do  projeto  que deseja 
3 - Vá em propiedades
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4 - CLique em Aplicativo
5 - Altere a Estrutura de Destino e pronto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando  que todos os projetos dentro  da solução devem  estar  na mesma  versão  para evitar erros de compilação.

Answer (score 2):

Abra as propriedades do projeto e altere a opção "Target Framework" para a versão do .NET Framework desejada... Note que se você utilizou alguma funcionalidade do .NET Framework 4.6, ao alterar o target framework para alguma inferior, você vai receber erros de compilação... E não existe uma maneira automática de fazer a conversão do 4.6 para uma inferior (somente ao contrário)...

Mas, se você não utilizou nenhum recurso do .NET 4.6, você não vai ter problema algum...

Answer (score 1):

Abra o arquivo .csproj e altere a tag `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>` com a versão que deseja utilizar.